# How do I add a "count up" timer to my video app - iOS

Tags: ios, video, nstimer

My application allows the user to record video. It does NOT use the UIImagePickerController, nor do I wish it to. At current the app displays a red "REC" button in the camera view controller while the app is capturing video. I would like to add a count up timer when recording starts to...indicate how much time the app has been recording video.

Here is some sample code how we have the "REC" button configured;

-(void)btn_start_recording_clicked
{

```
if (!WeAreRecording)
{
    custom_log(@"Start Recording");
    [self performSelector:@selector(record_animation) withObject:nil    afterDelay:2.0];
    img_stop_video_rec.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"start_recording.png"];
```

I cannot find anything on this. Help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm suprprised you managed to make an app that does video recording but not be able to make a count up timer :D I've added a demo app below, see if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

You need to invalidate your timer to stop the count up:

```
-(void)stopTimer
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.lblTimer.alpha = 0;
    }];
}
```

This is the new viewDidLoad() method where you create a UITapGesture. I don't know how your app works but I'd say you should have a stop record button and connect it to the above method. My new viewDidLoad() method for looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(stopTimer)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    self.lblTimer = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.lblTimer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.lblTimer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.lblTimer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:32];

    self.lblTimer.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.lblTimer addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];




    // set the starting total seconds
    self.totalSeconds = 0;

    [self setTimerTextWithTotalSeconds:self.totalSeconds];

    [self.view addSubview:self.lblTimer];

    // adding constraints
    id views = @{@"lblTimer": self.lblTimer};

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[lblTimer]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lblTimer]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // start the timer
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Have you tried something something like this:

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lblTimer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int totalSeconds;


@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.lblTimer = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.lblTimer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.lblTimer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.lblTimer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:32];

    // set the starting total seconds
    self.totalSeconds = 0;

    [self setTimerTextWithTotalSeconds:self.totalSeconds];

    [self.view addSubview:self.lblTimer];

    // adding constraints
    id views = @{@"lblTimer": self.lblTimer};

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[lblTimer]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lblTimer]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // start the timer
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)setTimerTextWithTotalSeconds:(int)totalSeconds
{
    int remainder = 0;

    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    remainder = totalSeconds % 3600;

    int minutes = remainder / 60;
    remainder = remainder % 60;

    int seconds = remainder;

    NSString *strTotalTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

    self.lblTimer.text = strTotalTime;
}

// ----------------------------------------
// Adds 1 second to total seconds
// ----------------------------------------
-(void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.totalSeconds += 1;

    [self setTimerTextWithTotalSeconds:self.totalSeconds];
}
```

You should see something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Zhang; this worked well, thanks! There is one problem. It doesn't stop. In my app the user double-taps the screen to stop recording. I need the timer to stop and disappear when the user double-taps. Any thoughts?

Comment: also since i added the timer the application now saves video every .5 seconds. I let it go for 10 seconds and when i exited to the gallery there were 20 new videos. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know how you record videos sorry. Create a new Stackoverflow question and paste your code where you perform the save video operation. Others might be able to help you.

Comment: do you know how to stop and reset the timer?

Comment: @user3294722 did you seriously write a video app ? I'm starting to be skeptical lol. I already gave you the code above on how to stop the timer. To reset the timer, you clear the totalSeconds property and then update the text label.